# Catch wrong input in C

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to create a program in C that reads lines from stdin and interprets each line as two integers. In case of erroneous input, the program outputs an usage help onto stderr. Now my code doesnt do what I need. It works only with 2 numbers on input. How can I edit my code to get the desired result?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a,b;

    if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2)
    {   
        // some code here
    }
    else
    {
        fputs("Wrong input\n", stderr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]
On the input `4 5 6` it should print `"Wrong input"`. But it just takes 4 and 5 and then can do something with these variables.

Comment: Hello, have you included `#include <stdio.h>`? I copied your code into a test application and added that include, and it works fine.

Comment: What does it mean, *It works only with 2 numbers on input. How can I edit my code to get the desired result?* What is the desired result?

Comment: Of course I included <stdio.h>. When I input e.g. 3 integers then it should print "Wrong input". But it doesnt. It just takes first two integers and do smth with it.

Comment: @user2950602 Okay, that has enlightened us a bit. You should put that in your question along with more information on what your "desired result" is and what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function is doing what it is suppose to do, which is capture your input and store them into variables. It reads up to a certain number of arguments and ignores the read of the input. `scanf` returns the number of items in the argument list that have been successfully filled (as noted in this link [C++ reference scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf)). There are different ways to handle the extra input, like this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b;
    char szExtra[256];

    if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2)
    {
        gets(szExtra);

        if (szExtra[0] != '\0')
        {
            fputs("Wrong input\n", stderr);
        }
        // some code here
    }
    else
    {
        fputs("Wrong input\n", stderr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) will capture the extra input and store it into the char array `szExtra`. If the first character in the array is `'\0'` then that means that there was no extra input. Note though that this will think that there was extra input if you input something like "1 2 " since `gets` will detect that extra `' '` space character. So you will have to modify your application a bit or find a better solution for handling the extra input.